# Route API not working for some waypoints

Tags: here-api

https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id[app_id]&app_code[app_code]&mode=fastest%3Btruck&representation=display&language=en-us&waypoint0=33.95%2C-117.4&waypoint1=34.43%2C-117.3&waypoint2=34.6%2C-117.33&waypoint3=34.6%2C-117.33&waypoint4=35.0%2C-117.65&waypoint5=35.13%2C-118.45&waypoint6=35.77%2C-119.25&waypoint7=36.51%2C-119.55&waypoint8=36.57%2C-119.61&waypoint9=36.57%2C-119.61&waypoint10=37.69%2C-122.14&waypoint11=37.6930555555%2C-122.1675

2.https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id[app_id]&app_code[app_code]&mode=fastest%3Btruck&representation=display&language=en-us&waypoint0=33.95%2C-117.4&waypoint1=34.43%2C-117.3&waypoint2=34.6%2C-117.33&waypoint3=34.6%2C-117.33&waypoint4=35.0%2C-117.65&waypoint5=35.13%2C-118.45&waypoint6=35.77%2C-119.25&waypoint7=36.51%2C-119.55

Route for these waypoints dont seem to be working.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/7943564

Answer (score 1):

I did have a look for the first request and it will be calculated the vehicle car without any issue. That points to and issue within the truck routing and the error message NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED underlines this assumption.

We have here an extended demo available which you can use for an analysis:

https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/fleet_telematics_api

If you add the waypoints there and calculate the truck route the error message points to waipoint 8. With a recalculation you can display a car route and have a look within the truck overlay where the possible connection issue lies.

[image]